# .Net Core RC2 MVC parameter is null in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core-rc2

Using .NET Core RC2 in VS Code I have the following HTML

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Connexion" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-4 input-group">
        <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And a controller

```
 [HttpPost("/Connexion")]
 public IActionResult Connexion([FromBody] string password)
 {
      return View();
 }
```

When submitting the form, it hits my breakpoint in the method but the password parameter is null. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Browsers use the `name` attribute of input controls to submit data to the server. The `id` attribute is a client-side thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form field **name** should match with the parameter name. So add a name attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe">
```

You may also remove the [FromBody] decoration.

```
[HttpPost("/Connexion")]
public IActionResult Connexion(string password)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Doing this and removing [FromBody] in the controller worked!